# To think kanji: 思う (おもう): シ (shi) versus (shitau)

Tags: kanji, dictionary, onyomi

Regarding the on'yomi shi (シ), of the character 思 from the word 思う, why does Google Translate list the pronunciation of this word/kanji as *shitau* instead of *shi* (with *shitau* missing from the dictionary entry as displayed below in Takoboto):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you refrain from pasting giant screenshots of your mobile phone into your questions? They do not add any clarity, but make the questions painful to view. Thankyou.

Comment: Maybe you can suggest how I can shrink them. I just added then to provide evidence that whatever I Ann saying is true, in case someone doesn't believe me. I just posted them to show that shitau is present in Google Translate but not in my dictionary. Thanks.

Comment: Use any image editor to shrink them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your specific question, of *" why does Google Translate..."* -- it is a machine program, and thus it is only as good as the data fed into it, combined with the cleverness of its algorithms.  Clearly, the programmers have not finished programming Google Translate to correctly handle Japanese.

In short: **Never trust Google Translate.**  Especially when it comes to single words.  The reading *shitau* is for the spelling 慕う, and it means "to yearn for, to long for".  思 on its own is read (generally) as *shi* and is only used this way in compounds with other kanji.

Comment: You mean to day I only user the on'yomi pronunciation of 思 when combined with other characters? Why is this? I mean, how does this compare with combinations of other characters? Thanks.

Comment: Why can't I see 思 on my keyboard input when I type "shi"? Using Swype Japanese keyboard. Thanks.

Comment: Software keyboards and IMEs (input method editors) use extensive dictionaries to try to provide useful autocomplete / autoconversion candidates.  The reading _shi_ is used by **lots** of potential kanji, so most IMEs won't bother offering 思 as a conversion candidate unless you've used this before.  Also, the _shi_ reading for 思 is again **only used in compounds**, more specifically **on'yomi compounds**.  If you haven't typed in the kana / romaji for the entire compound, the IME won't offer 思 as a candidate.  Full compounds include words like 思惑{しわく}, 思想{しそう},  思考{しこう}, etc.

Comment: Kun'yomi compounds will generally have okurigana between the 思 and the next kanji, like 思{おも}い合{あ}う, 思{おも}い浮{う}かべる, etc.